# Gridview shows the required data on localhost but fails to do so in remotehost

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, gridview, azure-sql-database

I am developing a web app in .net using c# and i have hosted my web app on Azure. My problem is when i run the web app on localhost it runs perfectly with the gridview showing desired data but when i do so at the remotehost the gridview doesn't show any data.

Design code for the page containing gridview is:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="100%">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Task" HeaderText="Task" SortExpression="Task" />
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowSelectButton="True" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database4CalConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Id], [Task] FROM [tablecal] WHERE ([Date] = @Date)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter DbType="Date" Name="Date" SessionField="tdate" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And the code for the page load is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["tdate"] = DateTime.Today;
    Session["task"] = "";
}
```

Comment: If data is not loaded maybe you should check that connection string is correct?

Comment: my connection string is the same for both of them @Aleksandr

Comment: How can connection string be the same for your local web app and an app hosted in Azure?

Comment: @Aleksandr i dont know but only thode pages which contain gridview are showing problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to check if the connections string is correct in your remote host.
Other problem may be the date parameter, if the language (and date format) of your first server is different from your second server. Sorry i couldn't simple comment in your question, 'coz I don't have any reputations here.

Hope it helps!